# How can we track the following data of youtube videos using google analytics in Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to track the total play duration,how many videos are completed,video ending time etc in android using Google analytics account.
I have created YouTube API and integrated in the application.I can see the real time data of active users. But how can I get above details of the YouTube videos using google analytics ?

Comment: If you meant how to put the youtube data into google analytics, look at their custom variables and metrics. But if you want to dump large JSON data per user, google analytics isn't the best choice.

Comment: How can I retrieve youtube video data like play time,played upto end or not in JSON format ? For which custom variable and metrics are you talking about ? Please can you tell me ? I want to use Google analytics only.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables As I said, you cannot use google analytics to dump json data more than 128 characters (including the custom variable name)